# Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'reactive'

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, package.json

I am using `"vue": "^3.0.0"` and trying to use some `Reactivity in Depth` from vue. But got the error

```
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'reactive'
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'ref'
```

Documentation here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#what-is-reactivity

More detail on `package.json`

```
"vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
"vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
...
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your dependencies is not compatible with Vue 3 - requiring Vue 2. So you have installed both versions.

You can try execute `npm explain vue` to find out which one is it...

Answer (score 2):

For whoever comes across this question, is using pnpm and running into this issue with all Vue exports, like:

```
Problems:
TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'defineComponent'.
TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'Component'.
TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'Ref'.
TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'ref'.
```

I noticed I had `"preserveSymlinks": true` in my `tsconfig.json`, removing it (or setting it to false) cleared the errors.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  // ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "preserveSymlinks": false // no more errors ✅
  }
}
```